# Add Subview to main view with function of subview class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I want to add my custom UIView to my main view.

I want to use the function initWithTitle:description: like:

```
AchievementView *achievement = [[AchievementView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" description:@"The Descr"]];
```

But this doesn't work. tThe initWithTitle:description: function have to be implemented as class method.

AchievementView.h

```
@interface AchievementView : UIView

@property (strong) NSString *achievementTtl;
@property (strong) NSString *achievementDescr;

@property (strong) UIView *theAchievementView;

- (void)initWithTitle:(NSString*)achievementTitle description:(NSString*)achievementDescription;
- (void)showAchievement;

@end
```

AchievementView.m

```
-(void)initWithTitle:(NSString*)achievementTitle description:(NSString*)achievementDescription {

    self.achievementTtl = achievementTitle;
    self.achievementDescr = achievementDescription;


}
- (void)showAchievement {

    // Create view popup
    self.theAchievementView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 423)];

    self.theAchievementView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    self.theAchievementView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.theAchievementView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    self.theAchievementView.layer.shadowOpacity = .15;
    [self.theAchievementView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


    [self addSubview:self.theAchievementView];


}
```

Call the method in main view:

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender { 
      AchievementView *achievement = [[AchievementView alloc] init];
      achievement.achievementTtl = @"Test";
      achievement.achievementDescr = @"TestDEscr";
     [achievement showAchievement];
}
```

I can't add the subview to the main view with this function. 
I think the "self" is wrong. What should be there?

```
[self addSubview:self.theAchievementView];
```

Comment: You are missing `alloc` in your code.  It should be `AchievementView *achievement = [[AchievementView alloc] initWithTitle...`

Comment: oops. i wrote it only to explain, what i want to do ;)

Comment: I'm a bit confused at what you're trying to do. Is all of this code for illustration, or is it real code? Because if it's real code, your initializers must be class methods and must follow certain conventions, ie, 

    + (id)init... 
    { 
        self = [super init]; 
        if (self) { /* initialize stuff */ } 
        return self;
    }

If you don't do that, self will always be null.

Comment: @Travis You're right. It wasn't right, what I wrote... Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 questions: how to initialize the view and how to add it to the screen.

You can use the `initWithTitle:description:` method, you just have to use it on an instance of the class, not the class itself:

```
[[AchievementView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" description:@"The Descr"]];
```

You are correct that you have the wrong `self` in your `addSubview` call. You need a reference to the parent view. You could pass it into your `AchievementView` class, but it is cleaner to manage that outside of the class.

I also noticed that `AchievementView` is a subclass of `UIView`, but you are creating another `UIView` inside it. It would be simpler to directly use the `AchievementView`. Your code should be similar to the below:

**AchievementView.h**

```
@interface AchievementView : UIView

@property (strong) NSString *achievementTtl;
@property (strong) NSString *achievementDescr;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)achievementTitle description:(NSString*)achievementDescription;

@end
```

**AchievementView.m**

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)achievementTitle description:(NSString*)achievementDescription {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 423)]) {
        self.achievementTtl = achievementTitle;
        self.achievementDescr = achievementDescription;

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = .15;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Main view**

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender { 
    AchievementView *achievement = [[AchievementView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" description:@"TestDEscr"];
    [self.view addSubview:achievement];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Number one, you are never adding `achievement` as a subview of your main view.  Basically you are creating a view offscreen, adding a view to that view, then moving on with whatever you want to do without ever moving the first view onto the screen.

As a minimum you should do this:

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender { 
      AchievementView *achievement = [[AchievementView alloc] init];
      achievement.achievementTtl = @"Test";
      achievement.achievementDescr = @"TestDEscr";
     [achievement showAchievement];
     [self addSubview:achievement];
}
```

Along with setting the frame size of `achievement` which is currently never set (and since most views by default mask to their layer bounds it will mask to (0,0,0,0)).

Then I would seriously reconsider how you are dealing with views and subviews.  If you do things properly, your `initwithtitle` will work just fine.